# How to avoid text overlap when using `multirow` in `longtable`?

Tags: memoir, longtable, multirow

I have a two column table. The first column contains (for eg) name and designation and second column has lots of text. I want the name and designation to stay close but on separate lines. For this I enter them on separate rows. However when I use `multirow` on second column, the text from one row starts overlapping text from subsequent rows. How can I avoid text from different rows from overlapping? The following code show some things I have been trying. I was trying to get to the contents formatted as on second page (last 2-3 rows) but want to avoid the text overlap.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

% \usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
% \usepackage{showframe}
% showframe does not show proper frame
\usepackage[margin=0.5in, showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\tablecolwidth}
\setlength{\tablecolwidth}{0.6\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}

\begin{longtable}{@{}lp{\tablecolwidth}@{}}
    \caption{Contents}\\
    \textbf{Col 1} & \textbf{Col 2} \\
    \midrule[0.25ex]
\endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable{}: continued}\\[1ex]
    \textbf{Col 1} & \textbf{Col 2} \\
    \midrule[0.25ex]
\endhead
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{Continued \ldots}\\
\endfoot
    \bottomrule[0.25ex]
\endlastfoot

Name       & \lipsum[2] \\
Designation & \lipsum[1] \\
\midrule

% Contents overflow on right
Name       & \multirow{2}{*}{\lipsum[2]} \\
Designation \\
           & \lipsum[1] \\
\midrule

% Contents of next row overlap subsequent rows and over flow page boundary
Name       & \multirow{2}{\tablecolwidth}{\lipsum[1-2]} \\
Designation \\
           & \lipsum[1] \\
\midrule

% Another way of limiting column width but overlap remains
Name       & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{\tablecolwidth}{\lipsum[2]}} \\
Designation \\
           & \lipsum[1] \\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Also when I use `fullpage` and `showframe`, I get incorrect frame. I was able to fix it using `geometry` package, but still wondering what the reason for the wrong frame is?

Edit, I was able to get the right formatting this way,

```
Name       & \multirow{1}{*}{\parbox{\tablecolwidth}{\lipsum[2]}} \\
Designation \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\
           & \lipsum[1] \
```

However I am still trying to find a better way to do this.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @egreg I have added more details.

Comment: If I understand the layout you want just use two p columns p{3cm}p{\colwidth} say then you don't need multirow just enter Name\newline Designation in one cell in the first column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Margins, `showframe`

Package `fullpage` does not support `memoir`. The class `memoir` is more complicate than the standard classes regarding the page layout. It provides additional length `\stockwidth`, `\stockheight` and another stuff like crop marks, …

The additional length `\spinemargin`, `\foremargin`, `\uppermargin`, `\lowermargin` are not supported by package `geometry`. After the new margins are set, these length have the wrong values. But package `showframe`/`eso-pic` supports `memoir` and uses some of these length.

They can manually be fixed:

```
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\spinemargin=\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax
\foremargin=\dimexpr\evensidemargin+1in\relax
\uppermargin=\dimexpr\topmargin+1in+\headheight+\headsep\relax
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{showframe}
```

But I do not recommend using `geometry` with `memoir`, because the class has its own methods for setting the page layout, e.g.:

```
\setlrmarginsandblock{.5in}{.5in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{.5in}{.5in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{showframe}
```

### Tabular

Perhaps you just want to have two `p`-columns, but without the width specification for the first? Then you can use a `tabular` inside the `longtable` to put the two entries in two lines in the first column:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\setlrmarginsandblock{.5in}{.5in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{.5in}{.5in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\namedes}[2]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}%
    #1\tabularnewline
    #2%
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\tablecolwidth}
\setlength{\tablecolwidth}{0.6\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}

\begin{longtable}{@{}lp{\tablecolwidth}@{}}
    \caption{Contents}\\
    \textbf{Col 1} & \textbf{Col 2} \\
    \midrule[0.25ex]
\endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable{}: continued}\\[1ex]
    \textbf{Col 1} & \textbf{Col 2} \\
    \midrule[0.25ex]
\endhead
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{Continued \ldots}\\
\endfoot
    \bottomrule[0.25ex]
\endlastfoot
\namedes{Name}{Designation} & \lipsum[2] \lipsum*[1]\\
\midrule
\namedes{Name}{Designation} & \lipsum[2] \lipsum*[1]\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: thank you. it was stupid of me to not try a nested tables. i also need to read the `memoir` manual.